# htaccess não funciona em subdiretório "online"

Tags: php, htaccess

Fiz um pequeno script que roda localmente dentro de uma pasta `(localhost/sistema)` até aí tudo certo, o problema começou a acontecer depois que eu tentei subir esse mesmo script para um servidor online (Hostgator), o que acontece é que as requisições na url não são capturas/enviadas para o index.php

ex:

```
URL local: localhost/sistema/aa/bb

URL online: sistema.com/sistema/aa/bb
```

o retorno do `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

URL local: `/sistema/index.php/aa/bb`

URL online: `/sistema/index.php`

Ou seja, não é capturado a URI completa no servidor online.

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

O que pode ser isso?

Comment: A última linha não deveria ser `RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`?

Comment: Mesmo comportamento